# Defining "myFootnote" in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes

I've done the following modifications:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
#1  \noindent \hb@xt@ .8em {\hss \@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother
```

But I want the code to be utilizible as a new independent command; for example, if I enter the `myFootnote` command, which is based on the behaviour of the default `footnote` command, I want my customized footnote to be appeared at the bottom of the page.

As you can see in the code, here is what I expect the code to do: The footnote number (or symbol), which is at the left and before the footnote-text, to be transformed to the right. Actually, I want the `\myFootnote{Hello}` to have the same spacing and font-size and all other specifications as in the `\footnote{Hello}` command, but the number and the counter (it's symbol) to be placed at the right of the footnote text.

I've changed the default footnote module in the LaTeX for the aforementioned code, which is what I *don't* want! I want the default LaTeX behaviour intact, and to have a new independent command (based on the default behaviour) applicable through the `\myFootnote{Hello}` command. So, how may I do that?

Comment: `to be transformed to the right`  means right (margin) or the end of line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate your footnotes from the default structure I would consider the package `manyfoot`, where you can have several series of footnotes. But, now to the answer of the question. As I understand you want the same series as the default footnotes. You have redefined `\@makefntext` which is used by `\footnote` to set the text in the footnote. To have your own look of `\MyFootnote` you need to start by defining your own footnote. Starting with `\footnote` it uses `\@footnotetext`, which in turn uses `\@makefntext`. Taking the default definitions from `latex.ltx` and `\@makefntext` as defined in `article` and `book` as a start, and making new commands gives the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{body={5cm,5cm}}%% A very small page

\makeatletter
\def\MyFootnote{\@ifnextchar[\@xfootnote{\stepcounter\@mpfn
     \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
     \@footnotemark%
     \@MyFootnotetext%  %%%% New comand
   }}
%%%
\long\def\@MyFootnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makeMyFntext{%  %%%% New command
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%
%%%%
\long\def\@makeMyFntext#1{%
  \rule{1.8em}{0pt}% %% Added to get same spacing as default
  #1  \noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\hss }}%% \hss moved to get left alignment
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Text text\footnote{Test.}.
More text\MyFootnote{Test again.}.
Even More text\footnote{Yet another footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as a side comment, I do think it looks a bit strange, more like a new footnote, and I don't think it will help the reader. Again I would recommend `manyfoot` to separate different footnote series.

Comment: I appreciate your awesome correct answer, thanks; but I've encountered another cumbersome issue hoping you can take a look at it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319533/71461