# The capability of inserting footnotes in the "longtabu" environment when the "XePersian" package is included

Tags: xetex, footnotes, tabu, longtabu

Using the XeTeX engine and specially the XePersian package, I came accross a cumbersome issue! I got my [customized footnote command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319505/95700) (`\MyFootnote`) which is working fine except in a *multipaged* "`longtabu`" environment (it seems to be also working fine in a "`longtabu`" environment which is fitted in a single page.) The problem happens when I put my footnotes inside a table that is spanned over multiple pages; It does insert the footnote notations in the table, but the corresponding actual footnote text (which should have been appeared at the bottom of the page) doesn't show up! It's an annoying issue which seems to be specific to the package and the engine I *have to* work with! I actually don't want to use the two incompatible XePersian commands of `\LTRfootnote{}` and `\RTLfootnote{}`. Please, help me figure out of the problem. I do appreciate your help :)

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{body={10cm,5cm}}%% A very small page

\makeatletter
\def\MyFootnote{\@ifnextchar[\@xfootnote{\stepcounter\@mpfn
     \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
     \@footnotemark%
     \@MyFootnotetext%  %%%% New comand
   }}
%%%
\long\def\@MyFootnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makeMyFntext{%  %%%% New command
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%
%%%%
\long\def\@makeMyFntext#1{%
  \rule{1.8em}{0pt}% %% Added to get same spacing as default
  #1  \noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\hss }}%% \hss moved to get left alignment
\makeatother
‎‎‎
% ‎Long tables‎ 
‎\usepackage{longtable}‎‎
% booktable‎
\usepackage{booktabs}‎
% tabu ‎package ‎for ‎tables‎
\usepackage{tabu}‎‎
% ‎tabularx‎
‎\usepackage{tabularx}‎‎‎‎
% footnote‎
\usepackage{bidiftnxtra}‎
% threepart table‎
\usepackage{threeparttablex}‎
\usepackage{tablefootnote}‎
‎
‎\usepackag‏e{zref-perpage}‎
% ‎\zmakeperpage{footnote}‎
% ‎footnote and reset footnote everypages‎
‎\usepackag‏e{perpage}‎
‎\MakePerPage{footnote}‎‎

‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}‎

\begin{document}
\noindent‎

‎\begin{flushleft}‎
\MyFootnote{\lr{Hello, I'm here}\raggedright}
\lr{This footnote works fine‎}
\end{flushleft}‎

‎‎
\begin{longtabu} to 1‎\textwidth ‎{|‎X[3,L]‎|c|X[2,r]|}‎‎‎
‎\caption{‎‏گزیده‌ای از فرمول‌های ارائه شده برای پارامتر بهنگام‌سازی روش‌های گرادیان مزدوج}‎‎‏‎‎
‎\label{1.2.table}‎
‎‎\\\hline‎‎
‏\rowfont[c]‏{\bfseries} ‎${‎\beta_k}‎$‎&‎
‎ ‎‏سال &‎
‎ ‎‏ارائه‎ دهندگان‎
\\\hline‎‎
‎$‎\beta_k^H = ‎\frac{g_k^T y_{k-1}}{d_{k-1}^Ty_{k-1}}‎‎$  & ‎‎
‎‎‎$1952$‎‎‏ ‏& ‎‎
‎‎‎‎‏هستنس و ‎استیفل‎
\MyFootnote{\lr{MyFootnote 2}\raggedright}.‎‎
\footnote{\lr{footnote 2}}
‎\\‎‎\hline‎‎‎
‎$‎\beta_k^H = ‎\frac{g_k^T y_{k-1}}{d_{k-1}^Ty_{k-1}}‎‎$  & ‎‎
‎‎‎$1952$‎‎‏ ‏& ‎‎
‎‎‎‎‏هستنس و ‎استیفل‎
\MyFootnote{\lr{MyFootnote 2}\raggedright}.‎‎
\footnote{\lr{footnote 2}}
‎\\‎‎\hline‎‎‎
‎$‎\beta_k^H = ‎\frac{g_k^T y_{k-1}}{d_{k-1}^Ty_{k-1}}‎‎$  & ‎‎
‎‎‎$1952$‎‎‏ ‏& ‎‎
‎‎‎‎‏هستنس و ‎استیفل‎‎
\footnote{\lr{Hello}}
\MyFootnote{\lr{Salam}\raggedright}.‎‎

‎\\‎‎\hline‎‎
\end{longtabu}
‎
‎\begin{flushleft}‎
\MyFootnote{\lr{Where are they?}\raggedright}
\lr{In this page, I'm okey too‎}
\end{flushleft}‎‎

‎\end{document}‎
```

The followings are the output pages 1 and 2 respectively (the red circles are added manually to the images, that indicate the footnote notations inserted appropriately, but the corresponding footnote text doesn't appear at the bottom of the page)
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is both `\footnote` and your `\MyFootnote` that have this problem. You could try to set the footnote mark in the table using `\footnotemark` and writing the text outside using `\footnotetext{text}`. Both commands have an optional argument to specify the number. But then you would need to define your own `\MyFootnotetext` in the same way as `\MyFootnote`. Unfortunately I have some problems copy-pasting your MWE. And the Persian fonts.

Comment: @StefanH I've already done that (and other solutions found online), with no luck; if you can, please provide a working example.